# Error in constructing an RDD of Tuples in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm constructing an RDD which contains Tuples, however it looks like there is something wrong. Here is my code

```
val RDD2= RDD1.filter {x => x.Tags.get.contains("xxx")}.map{y => {
    val month = y.CreationDate.get.split("-")(1)
    (month, 1)
    }
  }.reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b)

val v = RDD2.take(1)._1
```

`RDD1` contains objects of `Post` defined as follows

```
case class Post(Id: Option[String], Type: Option[String], CreationDate: Option[String], Tags: Option[String])
```

`RDD2` should contains Tuples and I would like to get the first element (_1) of the first Tuple. However it looks like `RDD2.take(1)` is an `Array[(String,Int)]`. Why? why it is not a Tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the API [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD), `take` returns an `Array[T]`

```
def take(num: Int): Array[T]
```

You can use `RDD.first` instead to get the first tuple in your RDD